# Android's flipper won't flip

Tags: android, viewflipper

I made a `GridView` gallery of image thumbnails, and I want the application to show the selected thumbnail in full size in next screen (full screen).

I have the image in in full size, thus I don't have to re-size it, but the problem that flipper won't flip.

My `onItemSelected` method looks like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
        View view, int i, long l) {

    if (gridLayout.isActivated()) {
        fullImage.setImageBitmap(
            downloadImage(listOfImages.get(i).getImgURLs()[1].getUrl()));
        flipper.showNext();
    }
}
```

and the main.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/lLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:orientation="vertical">
   <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:orientation="vertical">
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"  />
      </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/oneImageLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:orientation="vertical">
         <Button android:id="@+id/flipMeBack"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Flip Me!"
          />
         <ImageView android:id="@+id/wholeImage"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />   </LinearLayout>
  </ViewFlipper>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code for flipper looks okay to me, maybe the problem is somewhere else.
try using this and see if it works.

> flipper.setDisplayedChild(1);

If nothing works then try using a view switcher instead of flipper.

Comment: that doesn't work either. I really don't won't to use another activity, maybe there is something I didn't added to the app, or to the flipper? Is it right to use flipper in my case anyway?

Comment: declare x, Use-- System.out.println(x);x++;  After every statement and figure out what is being called and what isn't by Looking at logcat, value of x would be printed there. 
then post the results here.

Comment: I, did not see you're reply, so I decided to use the view switcher (it's first time I use it, as the flipper to), could you tell me what I do in order to pass the new Activity the bitmap of the image I want to display in the second Activity. I found an example in internet where there using an Intent which receives two parameters, one of them is the new activity, is it the way I pass the bitmap two, as the first parameter (because it can not except bitmap instance).